# Postgresql - How to read xmlattributes on xml?

Tags: java, postgresql

I Have xml :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<attachments>
  <entry file="cewe_gw.jpg" name="cewe_gw.jpg"/>
  <entry file="wp1827515.png" name="wp1827515.png"/>
</attachments>
```

I want to get list file?
ex:

```
cewe_gw.jpg
wp1827515.png
```

Comment: Why the Java tag? Are you looking for a SQL solution or  Java solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=e67cd8eaa0454891bee1976d3dc8f1d9)

To select any element or attribute, you can use XPath:

```
SELECT 
    xpath('//entry/@file',xml)
FROM mydata
```

This returns an array of file attributes. You can extract them using `unnest()`

```
SELECT 
    unnest(xpath('//entry/@file',xml))
FROM mydata
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a Postgres solution, then you can use `xmltable` for this:

```
select x.*
from the_table t
  cross join xmltable('/attachments/entry'
                      passing t.the_xml_column
                      columns file text path '@name') as x
```

This returns the value of the attribute `name`, if you want the `file` attribute, you need to change `@name` to `@file`

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=a0d17c7b2aa7757427235963e9784f92)

Comment: an ERROR:  syntax error at or near "passing"

Comment: Wow, never knew about `xmltable`. Thanks for showing.

Comment: @sahroni then you are using an outdated Postgres version